# Aeterna Noctis level building/assets, How do they do it for the walkable layer?

Tags: unity, assets, level-design, art

I have been following a game called Aeterna Noctis: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdCSCvSuZ6k

This game has been made in unity and I'm really curious about how did they create the walkable layer assets/level editing for the game.

The background and foreground layers (the ones in front of and behind the walkable layer) seem just a bunch of layered images. More or less the same as Hollow knight. But I am really curious about the walkable area. Sometimes it seems just a tiled game, others big images placed at needed places and others seem like Sprite shapes.

Do anybody know how do they create it?

Comment: We usually can't answer questions of the form "how did game X achieve feature Y". Unless the original creators have published a dev blog or conference talk detailing the under-the-hood workings of the feature, they're the only ones who know for sure, and they might never see your question, or if they do, they might be barred from answering by non-disclosure agreements. If you're interested in implementing a similar feature in your game, you'll usually get better answers faster by asking "How can I implement Y in my game" — then any answer that helps you do that is fair game.

Comment: For unity game you can guess it by looking at the game's assets files. ([AssetStudio](https://github.com/Perfare/AssetStudio)).